# QML ColorAnimation easing.type

Tags: qt, qml

I try to add an easing curve to my QML ColorAnimation :

```
ColorAnimation on color{
   id: colorAnimIn
   from: "Yellow"
   to: "dark gray"
   duration: 150

   easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
}
```

But i get a Property assignment expected error on the easing.type: line

Any idea ? the doc states it's correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug.

```
ColorAnimation {
    id: colorAnimIn
    from: "Yellow"
    to: "dark gray"
    duration: 150

    target: root
    property: 'color'

    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
}
```

is working. It seems to expect the property `property` to be set explicitly.
So it does not work with the 'on property'-version.